# Next.js 13.4, the UseAmp functionality is not functioning in the App route folder without the 'use client' directive

Tags: next.js

In Next.js 13.4, the UseAmp functionality is not functioning in the App route folder without the 'use client' directive.

As per the Next.js 13 documentation, the routing mechanism has been revised to function from the app folder, resulting in all pages within the app folder being recognized as server components. To enable AMP functionality, it's advised to make use of hooks like 'useAmp()'. However, using the 'useAmp()' hook within the app folder may not function properly within a server component unless the 'use client' directive is incorporated. When this directive is added, then page transitioning it from Server-Side Rendering (SSR) to that of a client-side page.